# How do I write a spec for a function that contains special characters?

Tags: elixir, typespec

I have some macros that define functions that have special characters. Specifically ":" and ".". Is it possible to write a spec definition for functions with those characters in it?

```elixir
defmodule UniqueCharacters do
  defmacro make_wild_function_name do
    function_name = String.to_atom("baz:foo.bar")
    quote do
      def unquote(function_name)(), do: :ok
    end
  end
end

defmodule TestSpec do
  import UniqueCharacters

  #This next line doesn't work
  @spec baz:foo.bar() :: :ok
  make_wild_function_name()
end
```

This produces the following error:

```elixir
** (SyntaxError) lib/unique_characters.ex:14: keyword argument must be followed by space after: baz:

    (elixir) lib/kernel/parallel_compiler.ex:229: anonymous fn/4 in Kernel.ParallelCompiler.spawn_workers/7
```

Is there a way to escape the characters in the function spec so that this will compile without removing the spec? I can change the ":" to "_" or something more well behaved but the "." is basically non-negotiable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you specify the typespec in your macro? If so, this seems to work fine:

```elixir
defmodule UniqueCharacters do
  defmacro make_wild_function_name do
    function_name = String.to_atom("baz:foo.bar")
    quote do
      @spec unquote(function_name)() :: :ok
      def unquote(function_name)(), do: :ok
    end
  end
end

defmodule TestSpec do
  import UniqueCharacters

  make_wild_function_name()
end
```

I feel like bundling the typespec with the definition makes the most sense; is that enough?

Edit: Looks like this also works, although kinda messy:

```elixir
defmodule UniqueCharacters do
  defmacro make_wild_function_name do
    function_name = String.to_atom("baz:foo.bar")
    quote do
      def unquote(function_name)(), do: :ok
    end
  end
end

defmodule TestSpec do
  import UniqueCharacters

  @spec unquote(:'baz:foo.bar')() :: :ok
  make_wild_function_name()
end
```

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect. I think in my actual project I can make another macro that regenerates the function name for writing specs since in my actual project there are some function parameters that are the same for every function.